# External keyboard configuration on ChromeOS?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, keyboard-layout, chrome-os

I have connected an external keyboard to my Acer Chromebook via USB but a few keys seem odd. Windows key was expected to open the search, but it acts like Alt.